# Правильная архитекрура REST API

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

У меня возник вопрос при написании API на FAST API. Вот у меня есть api, который возвращает данные из бд в json формате.
После я хочу сделать фронт для приложения и как связать эти две части так, что они следовали RESTFUL принципу "Отделение клиента от сервера"?

Допустим, у меня есть адрес test.com/api/products при отправления запроса на который, нам возвращается ответ в виде json.
Теперь я хочу чтобы по адресу test.com/products мне возвращалась html страница с данными.

Как правильно разделить эти части?

**Пример:**

Вот есть api router, он возвращает json.

```py
@router.get("/api/products")  
async def get_operations(operation_type: str, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):  
    query = select(operation).where(operation.c.type == operation_type)  
    result = await session.execute(query)  
    return {  
        "status": "success",  
        "data": result.mappings().all(),  
        "detail": None  
    }
```

Я связывал это так.

```py
@router.get("/products", response_class=HTMLResponse)  
def get_page(request: Request, operations=Depends(get_operations)):  
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "data": operations})
```

Но я не понимаю, является ли это корректным разделением.
Может мне нужно создавать два отдельных приложения, и во фронт-приложение отправлять запросы по адресу /api/products, чтобы получить json, который впоследствии будет отправляться на собранной html страницы.
Эта идея мне кажется чересчур сложной, но может это и есть разделение..

Буду рад, если поможете разобраться мне с данным вопросом!

Comment: Если вы решили работать с API, то генерация html это вообще не забота сервера. Это уже забота фронт приложения получить данные в json и отобразить их клиенту в том виде как ему надо. Вот когда озаботитесь СЕО-оптимизацией, тогда может портебоватся генерация html на стороне сервера. Но современные фреймверки клиентских приложений имеют для этого режим SSR

Comment: Но не забываем, что "правильный" и "быстрый" это разные вещи. Сайты со сборкой всего на клиенте обычно тяжелы. Однако сборка html на сервере грузит ваши сервера, вместо клиента. Так же помним, что может захотеться сделать мобильное приложение, которое вообще не на html. Всегда надо взвешивать какой подход нужен в конкретной задаче под конкретной нагрузкой